в чем разница между .cpp и .cxx?
Начал недавно писать на c++ и узнал что есть .cpp .cxx и просто .c.. с .c все ясно, а вот чем отличается .cpp и .cxx так и не понял.

в первом имени есть две буквы p, а во втором две буквы x.

Да хоть .c++, если файловая система позволяет. Главное, как компилировать, а не какое расширение...

@user7860670 Мне все же кажется, что это не дубликат - в том смысле, что вопрос, конечно, достоин закрытия, но пояснение разницы заголовочных файлов и файлов реализации все же не поясняет, что никакой разницы между расширениями нет.

@Harry Там в ответе прямо поясняется, для чего нужны  .cpp и .cxx.

@user7860670 Я читал тот ответ. Там ничего не сказано ни о разнице, ни об одинаковости этих расширений. Просто для чего они нужны. Но нет явного указания, что функциональность с расширением не связана...

Согласен с Harry и переоткрыл.

Для C++ есть расширения файлов .C (большая буква),.с++, .cpp, .cxx.
В некоторых файловых системах + не мог быть частью имени файлов, а ткже не было разницы между большой и маленькой буквами (DOS, Windows). Там исторически сложилось именование через cpp.
Такое расширение перекачевало как практика и к другим программистам. Потом появились системы сборки и плюс мог там интерпретироваться человеком как регулярное выражение, маска, или арифметическое действие. Вместе с стремлением к кроссплатформенности это вытесняет использование ++ в имени файлов.
.cxx придумали для того чтоб не путать "C Pre Processor". Например в Makefile CPPFLAGS - переменная для препроцессора, а CXXFLAGS для Си плюсплюс.
Расширение файла не важно для компилятора, но для автоматических систем сборки нужно указывать. Например у меня недавно не собрался проект когда я заинклудил с++ класс в файл с расширением .с - переименовал в cpp.
Отличия cxx от cpp нет. Просто люди хотели чтоб другие не путались и запутали ещё сильнее.
